# simple network analysis doesn't give correct result

Tags: passive-networks

Well I tried to calculate the circuit below, because of little experience the calculation became terribly messy and I didn't solve it. I need to calculate the power given by the 3A current source.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9SE7g.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

First I summed the voltage & current sources. To a single voltage of 5V at the top and in the middle a source of 1.75A. Then I used superposition to calculate the voltage at the top (resulting in -2.5V)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS0EqP.png)</sup>

I thought I could then simply say "this 1.75A source pushes current from 0V down to -2.5V so the power is \$P = -2.5V \cdot 3A = -7.5W \$
Simulation shows this is wrong, how would I calculate this problem? With nodal analysis?

Answer (score 2):

To correctly apply superposition, you need to add the voltage due to the 1.75A current source in the right-hand circuit (which would be 1.75V) to the -2.5V due to the 5V voltage source in the left-hand circuit.  The result is -0.75V, not -2.5V.

Answer (score 0):

Just shifting things around and combining V1 and V2, you can get:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsQGtJ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You can then convert V1 and R1 to its [Norton equivalent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norton%27s_theorem). Simplify divide V1 by R1, and swap the voltage source for a current source, and put them in parallel, not series:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzcI37.png)</sup>

Now you can combine current sources and resistances, and the rest is pretty easy. Final result left as a homework exercise.